# Angular ng-repeat in select options showing extra space and not selecting default value.

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to show a list of years in a select box through angular's `ng-repeat` but it is showing an empty line before list of years and not showing selected value which should be first year in the list. you can see in code example. any help will be highly appreciated.

```js
 angular.module('F1FeederApp', ['F1FeederApp.controllers']);
 
  angular.module('F1FeederApp.controllers', []).

  /* Drivers controller */
  controller('driversController', function($scope) {
  
    $scope.years = getYearRange(); 
    
  });
  /* Year Range Code */
  function getYearRange() {
  var startYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  var endYear = 2005;
  var dateRange = [];

  while(endYear <= startYear) {
      dateRange.push(startYear);
      startYear -= 1
  }
  return dateRange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="F1FeederApp">
  <div ng-controller="driversController">  
      <select ng-model="F1s_Selection" class="btn btn-default">
       <option ng-repeat="year in years">{{year}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`ng-options`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) instead of `ng-repeat` it works and it's better.

```js
angular.module('F1FeederApp', ['F1FeederApp.controllers']);
angular.module('F1FeederApp.controllers', []).

  /* Drivers controller */
  controller('driversController', function($scope) {
  
    $scope.years = getYearRange(); 
    
  });
  /* Year Range Code */
  function getYearRange() {
  var startYear = new Date().getFullYear();
  var endYear = 2005;
  var dateRange = [];

  while(endYear <= startYear) {
      dateRange.push(startYear);
      startYear -= 1
  }
  return dateRange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="F1FeederApp">
  <div ng-controller="driversController">  
      <select ng-model="F1s_Selection" ng-options="year as year for year in years | orderBy:year track by years  " class="btn btn-default">
      </select>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your time. your solution is working but i need 2016 selected value.

Comment: Thank Alexis it's looking perfect, but if you inspect element and check the values of each option it is rendering all years in each value section, sorry to bother you :-D

Comment: thank you so much for your time, i got this by removing "s" from track by years. final code is <select ng-model="F1s_Selection" ng-options="year as year for year in years | orderBy:year track by year" class="btn btn-default">
      </select>

Comment: Nice ! no problem :-)

Answer (score 1):

The empty line is your default selected value because your model in empty.
To have a default selected value you need to sassing a value to your model:

```
$scope.years = getYearRange(); 
$scope.F1s_Selection = $scope.years[0];
```

And also as @Alexis's answer use `ng-options` instead of `ng-repeat`. It has a better performance.

Comment: i agree with you but in @Alexis's answer it is selecting 2005 instead of 2016.

Comment: @junaidfarooqui in that case you can choose the last item as selected `$scope.F1s_Selection = $scope.years[$scope.years.length-1];`

Answer (score 0):

please try  ng-init.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="F1FeederApp">
  <div ng-controller="driversController">  
      <select ng-init = "F1s_Selection = years[0]" ng-model="F1s_Selection" class="btn btn-default">
       <option ng-repeat="year in years">{{year}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The angular way is to use ng-options for this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="F1FeederApp">
  <div ng-controller="driversController">  
      <select ng-model="F1s_Selection" class="btn btn-default" ng-options"year in years">{{year}}</option>
      </select>
</div>
  </div>
```

and in controller set `F1s_Selection` with wanted default value like this:

```
$scope.F1s_Selection = years[0];
```